# Open an XPage from the Application Layout Banner

Tags: xpages, xpages-extlib

I'm using the Application Layout control and have set up a basicLeafNode within the bannerUtility links. I wanted to open another XPage (MeineAnmeldung.xsp) whenever that link 'Meine Anmeldungen' is clicked.

[image]

```
<bx:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
<xe:basicLeafNode
    label="Meine Anmeldungen">
    <xe:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.getUser().getRoles().contains('[CreateAnmeldung]')}]]></xe:this.rendered>
    <xe:this.onClick><![CDATA[#{javascript:context.redirectToPage("MeineAnmeldungen.xsp")}]]></xe:this.onClick>
</xe:basicLeafNode>
```

but, as I have discovered, the onCLick event on the basicLeafNode is strictly CSJS, which I assume is the reason why I'm having issues.

Am I trying to do this at the wrong place? To be honest, I don't understand the difference between all these different bars at the top: Placebar, Search Bar, Title Bar, mastHeader. No idea which does what, and I'm trying to have a very simple UI without any clutter.

Or is there a way to redirect using CCJS? Perhaps by recalculating an URL, which I also am not sure about how to calculate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a pageTreeNode instead. Here's an example:

```
<xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
    <xe:pageTreeNode label="Meine Anmeldungen" page="/MeineAnmeldungen.xsp.xsp"></xe:pageTreeNode>
</xe:this.bannerUtilityLinks>
```

Comment: Ah that's perfect! Wonderful. I would kiss you if you were near me. Thanks a bunch, Per!

Answer (score 1):

You can redirect via CSJS using location.href=.... CSJS is all the onClick event of the basicLeafNode can do.

The Application Layout control itself has an `onItemClick` event on the Events tab. That will allow you to trigger SSJS and use `context.getSubmittedValue()` to check the `submitValue` property (you'll need to add that) for the basicLeafNode.

See [TitleBar tabs in ApplicationLayout control (extlib) generating invalid code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9293852/titlebar-tabs-in-applicationlayout-control-extlib-generating-invalid-code)

Comment: Thanks Paul, I'm not going crazy then. So something like facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath() + "/MeineAnmeldung.xsp" then.

Comment: location.href="${javascript:facesContext.getExternalContext().getRequest().getContextPath()}/MeineAnmeldung.xsp" should work, I think. You're basically using SSJS to compute the context path on page load, then pass that into the CSJS written to the page. But Per's suggestion is the better practice approach ;-)